# remove the i'th link in a doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to remove a link in the location on the linked list that is passed to this method, however it is not working. I think my code is really bad, if the index is 0 then I think it will give me an error:

```
public void remove(int index)
{
    DLink iterator=_firstLink;
    int count=0;

    while(iterator!=_lastLink)
    {
         iterator=iterator._next;
         count++;
         if(count>=index)break;
    }
    if(index==count)
    {
        iterator._previous = iterator._next;

        _size--;

    } 
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            throw new Exception("IndexOutOfBoundException");
        } 
        catch (Exception e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't use a `LinkedList` ?

Comment: Please say why it doesn't work, what errors you are getting.

Comment: i want to do it myself

Comment: index out of bound exception

Comment: what is the input? How much list element, which index? This code is written to break with IndexOut... if index is greater than list size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the exception when index is 0 because of this code:

```
while(iterator!=_lastLink)
{
     iterator=iterator._next;
     count++;
     if(count>=index)break;
}
```

Step through line by line with index = 0. You immediately increment the count to 1, then break. So when you hit the comparison `index==count`, it evaluates to `0==1` which is false. So, it goes to the else and throws the exception.

Try putting the `if(count>=index)break;` line first.

Also, you'll need to update your first / head references for 0, which is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that you `count++;` and then check if it is the greater or equal than the index *after* you have already moved the iterator.
The `if(index==count)` is not satisfied and you will always hit the `else` with the throw exception

Do something like:

```
while(iterator!=_lastLink && index != count){  
   count++;  
   iterator=iterator._next;  
}
```

instead. This way for index equal 0 you don't go in the while loop and you can go in `if(index==count)`

Comment: Dont think that is the problem, has it been index==count++ then that would have been a problem

Comment: @mawia:See the update in answer